# How to create a PHP script that will generate new text daily?

Tags: php, mysql

I've researched this a lot but can't find a satisfactory answer; how do I create a PHP script that will generate a new number each day? Obviously I'm using this for a reason other than to generate a random number daily, but I won't go into that reason, it'll just make this question more complicated. So I'm asking this: How do I generate a random number which will change each day in PHP? Using MySQL will be no problem, but it must be automatic so I won't have to manually change it daily. (Here's my 'script' to generate a random number)

```
<?php
echo rand(1,100)
?>
```

Any answers are appreciated, Thanks
- Hugh

Comment: "It'll make the question more complicated" and thus, another XY problem is born: xyproblem.info

Comment: So... if you call the script two times on the same day, should it return the same number? Simplest way is to store the number somewhere (like a database or text file), and when the script runs check if a number already exists for the current date. If so, return it; if not, generate one and store it.

Comment: As for the question at hand, if you're mostly keyed on keeping the same result for the duration of the day (and are using mysql to store it instead of a random file), then just make an sql routine which sets the value every 24 hours. That or when you query the info, have a timestamp to determine if it needs updating.

Comment: I would just predefine a random number for every day you will ever need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fairly a simple task as long as you understand the basics of crontabs.

**Step One:** Create the script. This is basically going to be what creates the "text" then inputs it into the database via mysqli. For example, if we are generating a random number, what you have so far is good, you will just need to insert it into a database table. I recommend using a time stamp to give what day it was generated on

**Step Two:** Create a cronjob. Use the servers crontab to run a task every day, this can be done by adding this to the cron file: This will run a cron each new day.

```
00 01 * * * php path/to/your/generate.php
```

**Step Three** Fetch result from database by using the current date. If you are needing to display that text, pull it from the database using whatever the current day is from `date() or DateTime`

Answer (score 3):

Use `time()` function to generate seed, then use regular rand.
This way you should't to store it anywhere and you always can regenerate it when needed.

```
function randomEveryDay()
{
    $now = time();
    $today = $now - ($now % 86400); //86400 = 1 day in seconds
    srand($today);
    return rand();
}
```

Or more interesting example without random at all.

```
function randomEveryDay() {
    $now = time();
    $today = $now - ($now % 86400);
    $hash = sha1('salt string'.$today);
    return intval('0x' . substr($hash, 6, 8));
}
```

Every day you will get the same number in `$today`, then use any cryptographic\non cryptographic hash function to generate "random".

Comment: This is not really random at all, it's predictable. At least use [`mt_rand`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) instead of the garbage that is `rand()`.

Comment: For the idea it is not matter which PRNG you use. If you want you can use Mersenne Twister or not to use PRNG at all and replace it with cryptographic\non cryptographic hash function like murmurhash. There is only one requirement - the function must give the same result with the same input.

Comment: I'm mostly concerned that this number either needs to be random and unpredictable, something that's important because guessing it could lead to cheating or hacking of some sort, or it's just random junk that has to change to something unique each day.

Comment: Well, on a scale of 1 to 10 in terms of difficulty to crack that's about a 3, but better than nothing I guess.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to give a good answer without knowing exactly what you want to do, so this will generate a new number every day:

```
echo date('Ymd');
```